# Binding/Listening to a port in Mac OSX Lion 10.7.2 fails

Tags: cocoa, sockets, listener, port, cfsocket

I am trying to set up a SilverLight policy server under MacOSX 10.7.2 (Lion).  This requires that I create and bind a socket to port 943, since SilverLight requests the policy file on this port.  Unfortunately, it seems I am unable to bind at that port, as the bind call fails with `errno=49.`  I suppose I do not have access to this port.  Perhaps I need root privileges?  Or do I need to forward this port to another one that I can bind?  I'm a bit new to network programming, so any help is greatly appreciated!  I've also attached my source code.  Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, although it works fine if I use the SilverLight restricted ports 4502-4532, which SilverLight communicates on once the policy file is successfully served.

```
- (void) start {
    CFSocketRef socket = CFSocketCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (!socket) {
        [self errorWithName:@"Unable to create socket."];
        return;
    }

    int reuse = true;
    CFSocketNativeHandle fileDescriptor = CFSocketGetNative(socket);
    if (setsockopt(fileDescriptor, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                   (void *)&reuse, sizeof(int)) != 0) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to set socket options.");
        return;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
    address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
    address.sin_port = htons(943);
    CFDataRef addressData = CFDataCreate(NULL, (const UInt8 *)&address, sizeof(address));
    [(id)addressData autorelease];

    CFSocketError error = CFSocketSetAddress(socket, addressData);
    if (error < 0) {
        NSLog(@"Error bind %d\n", errno);  //fails here for port 943.
        return;
    }

    NSFileHandle *listeningHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc]
                   initWithFileDescriptor:fileDescriptor
                   closeOnDealloc:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
          addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(receiveIncomingConnectionNotification:)
                 name:NSFileHandleConnectionAcceptedNotification
               object:nil];

    [listeningHandle acceptConnectionInBackgroundAndNotify];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `root` has privileges for ports below 1024.  Try running your code with `sudo` and see if that fixes your issue.

*Edit:*

Also, check out `man strerror`.  It will take that relatively meaningless error code and give you a (slightly) more useful string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  printf("%s\n", strerror(49) );
  return 0;
}
```

Gives:

```
Can't assign requested address
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, if I run it with sudo, it no longer fails.  Also, I found out that I must first zero out the sockaddr_in struct and set the sin_len field.  Then, prior to running it with sudo, I was actually getting errno=13, which is permission denied.  Thanks again for your response.

Comment: No problem -- since this worked for you, you can accept my answer so others can more easily find the solution.

Comment: Absolutely... I selected the green checkmark, which I assume does the trick.  However, I wonder if there is a way to accomplish this without having root access.  For example, perhaps by doing some kind of forwarding of port 943 to one that does not require root access?